# How to have Gitlab pipeline copy to a directory depending on branch name

Tags: gitlab-ci

This Gitlab pipeline job builds Gitbook documentation and copies it to some place:

```
build_gitbook:
  variables:
    DOC_DIR: '/var/www/doc'
  script:
    - gitbook build help _book
    - 'rm -rf $DOC_DIR/help'
    - 'mkdir -p $DOC_DIR/help'
    - 'cp -r _book/* $DOC_DIR/help'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - _book
    expire_in: 10 mins
```

How do I change this job so that the documentation gets copied to /var/www/doc when the branch is master, but gets copied to to /var/www/dev-doc on all other branches?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to add to your `CI` jobs and not limited in number of the jobs, you can use [only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic) syntax to change your `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
⋮
build_gitbook_master:
    variables:
        DOC_DIR: '/var/www/doc'
    only:
        - master
    script:
        ⋮
        <Your Scripts>
        ⋮
    artifacts:
        ⋮

build_gitbook_others:
    variables:
        DOC_DIR: '/var/www/dev-doc'
    except:
        - master
    script:
        ⋮
        <Your Scripts>
        ⋮
    artifacts:
        ⋮
⋮
```

Also you can check GitLab's [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) as an alternative way.

Comment: The thing is that this script is considerably more complicated in the read world and is frequently changing. It would be much better to maintain it in a single script instead of two. The risk of having two is that a developer changes one and forgets the other one.

Comment: @HelgiBorg by using [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#yaml-anchors-for-script) you are able to include a predefined list of commands in multiple jobs which leads to preserve from scripts duplication.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this. The main script is in the template part.

```
# The template part that contains the build script it self.
.build_gitbook: &gitbook_build_script
  script:
    - gitbook build common_operations_infos _book
    - 'rm -rf $DOC_DIR/help'
    - 'mkdir -p $DOC_DIR/help'
    - 'cp -r _book/* $DOC_DIR/help'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - _book
    expire_in: 10 mins

# Builds gitbook on the master branch
build_gitbook_master:
  <<: *gitbook_build_script
  variables:
    DOC_DIR: '/var/www/doc'
  only:
    - master

# Builds gitbook on other branch
build_gitbook_others:
  <<: *gitbook_build_script
  variables:
    DOC_DIR: '/var/www/dev-doc'
  except:
    - master
```

This is still not the perfect solution since this requires two jobs. If they are run in manual mode (*when: manual*) then the developer must choice the right job depending on branch.